# Need cronjob to take backup,zip and dev null files

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to create a cron job that will take backup of two logs file2.log and file2.log,zip those logs and devnull the file2.log and file2.log.After 7 days i want to delete those zip files.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

use the following command for backup and zip the file:
cp -p file1.log file1.log_back
tar -xvf file1.log_back.tar file1.log_back
gzip file1.log_back.tar file2.log_back.tar

write a shell program with this command as per requirement and add that to crontab using crontab -e